# Webpack extract js with html literal in html file

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a js file like this

```
const link = () => {
   return '<p>my text </p>'
}
```

I want to use webpack to return an html file with :

```
<p>my text </p>
```

Which loader i need to use ? Do you have an example webpack config ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you would like to create an HTML file from your js file.

If would look for 'static site generators' much like this one:

- https://github.com/markdalgleish/static-site-generator-webpack-plugin

If you are not using a . framework like react or angular, you may have to use a templating language instead like handlebars or [ejs](http://ejs.co/).

here are some examples of how to start putting the site together:

- https://github.com/markdalgleish/static-site-generator-webpack-plugin/tree/master/test/success-cases

your **index.js** file might look more like :

```
module.exports = function(locals) {
  return locals.template({ html: '<h1>' + locals.path + '</h1>' });
};
```

Which would be combined with a **template.ejs** file like :

```
<html>
  <body>
    <%- html %>
  </body>
</html>
```

and a wabpack config file like:

```
var StaticSiteGeneratorPlugin = require('static-site-generator-webpack-plugin');
var StatsWriterPlugin = require("webpack-stats-plugin").StatsWriterPlugin;
var ejs = require('ejs');
var fs = require('fs');

var template = ejs.compile(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/template.ejs', 'utf-8'))

var paths = [
  '/',
  '/foo',
  '/foo/bar'
];

module.exports = {
  entry: __dirname + '/index.js',

  output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    path: __dirname + '/actual-output',
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
  },

  plugins: [
    new StaticSiteGeneratorPlugin({
      paths: paths,
      locals: {
        template: template
      }
    }),
    new StatsWriterPlugin() // Causes the asset's `size` method to be called
  ]
};
```